# Excel Copy and keep

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to have excel copy the contents of "B1" to "A1" and keep the contents in "A1" even if "B1" is deleted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If `B1` contains *data* rather than a *formula*, just copy `B1` and paste into `A1`.

If `B1` contains a *formula*, then click on `B1` and click on *Copy*.  Then click on `A1` and click on *PasteSpecial Value*.   This will preserve the current value of `B1` in `A1`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this may be through Excel VBA. VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) is a programming language that can be used to automate tasks in Excel and other Office applications.

Since you didn't give us much information, this is a **very** simple script. You would need to expand it to check for errors. (This won't work if you modify multiple cells at once, for example.)

To do this:

1. Open the workbook and click on the worksheet where you would like this task done.
2. Right click on the worksheet's tab and click *View Code*.
3. A separate window should open with a blank document. Into that document, insert this code:

   ```vb
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Dim KeyCells As Range
       Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B10")

       If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           If Not Target.Value = "" Then
               Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value
           End If
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
4. Verify that the document is for the correct sheet and then close the code editor.

I'll explain this step by step:

1. `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` indicates that this code should run whenever a cell is changed in the worksheet.
2. `Dim KeyCells As Range` and `Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B10")` specifies the range that we're checking for changes. In this case I picked `B1:B10`, but you can change this to whatever you want.
3. `If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then` checks to see if the changed cell is in the range we want. (i.e. `B1:B10` in this case.) If it isn't, then we do nothing.
4. `If Not Target.Value = "" Then` checks if the value of the changed cell is an empty string. This way nothing changes when you delete.
5. `Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value` copies the value of the changed cell into the cell to its left. That is, if we change `B3`, then `A3` will be updated.
6. The rest just closes things out.

Here's a visual in case that's helpful:

[image]